# Вшить SQLite.Interop в exe с помощью Costura.Fody

Tags: c#, sqlite

После использования [Costura.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) почти все dll пошли в exe, но пару dll, которые в папках, не могу закинуть в exe.

В чём проблема ?
(в папках 2 dll от Sqlite)
[image: Папки]

Comment: Это нативные библиотеки, не управляемые.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov то есть их не скрыть, вообще ?

Comment: Скорее всего, никак.

Comment: Почему-то многие (обычно начинающие) разработчики хотят, чтобы их программа была в одном-единственном файле. Ну, запакуйте всё в zip-архив для поставки клиенту (один файл будет). Или сделайте инсталлятор (опять же один файл). Вариант для извращенцев: поместить эти нативные библиотеки в ресурсы. При старте приложения они извлекаются из ресурсов, помещаются в нужные папки (скорее всего путь жёстко задан в sqlite-провайдере), а при окончании работы удаляются.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я бы так не парился, но мне банально поставили задачу всё в один файл и не надо sfx архивов, вот я и мучаюсь, можно последний способ  поподробнее

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это нативные библиотеки, поэтому нужно указывать явно, что вы их тоже хотите вшить в exe.

1.
Нужно указать названия (только названия, включать расширение файлов не нужно) библиотек в файле `FodyWeavers.xml`.

```
<Weavers>
   <Costura>
      <Unmanaged32Assemblies>SQLite.Interop</Unmanaged32Assemblies>
      <Unmanaged64Assemblies>SQLite.Interop</Unmanaged64Assemblies>
   </Costura>
</Weavers>
```

2.
Создать в проекте папки `costura32` и `costura64` и поместить в них соответствующие версии библиотечных файлов.

3.
Указать действие при построении (Build Action) - встраиваемый ресурс (Embedded Resource)

Результат должен получиться примерно следующим

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примечание. Картинка взята из статьи [Including SQLite.Interop.dll into your C# project](https://idmedia.no/general/including-sqlite-interop-dll-into-your-c-project/)

Более подробную информацию можно найти в `README` на странице проекта на [гитхабе](https://github.com/Fody/Costura)

Comment: Куда это вводить ?  :D

Comment: К сожалению я ещё не имею доступа к чату
(Ваш способ не сработал или я что-то сделал не так)

Comment: не не работает https://i.imgur.com/QmrlZGL.png